# Why the DispatcherTimer delegate on work in WinRT?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

**the code below works in Windows Phone 7**

```
    private void ShowTime()
    {
        txtTime.Text = get24hour();

        //display the Date and week.
        DateTime nowtime = DateTime.Now;
        txtWeek.Text = nowtime.DayOfWeek.ToString();
        txtDate.Text = nowtime.Date.ToString("MM/dd");   

        //create timer to fresh to time
        DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
        timer.Tick += timer_Ticker;
        timer.Start();        
    }

    private void timer_Ticker(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtTime.Text = get24hour();
    }

    private string get24hour()
    {
        return DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm");
    }
```

**but error in WinRT (Metro)**

error part:

```
  timer.Tick += timer_Ticker;
```

error message:

```
  No overload for 'timer_Ticker' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler<object>'
```

**what I do**
I try to change the code to

```
    private void timer_Ticker()
    {
        txtTime.Text = get24hour();
    }
```

**result**
but it is not work again, why and how to solve it? :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
timer.Tick += new EventHandler<object>(timer_Tick); 

private void timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
{
}
```

Refer to [this link](http://www.devdiv.com/DispatcherTimer%E7%9A%84Tick%E6%80%8E%E4%B9%88%E8%AE%BE%E7%BD%AE%EF%BC%9F%E5%92%8Cwindows_phone%E4%B8%8D%E4%B8%80%E6%A0%B7%E4%BA%86%EF%BC%9F-thread-128080-1-1.html)

Answer (score 0):

I read the msdn and change the delegate method to below and it works:

```
    private void timer_Ticker(object sender, object e)
    {
        txtTime.Text = get24hour();
    }
```